# valuation ring is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

[image]

suppose $a$ and $a'$ are units of $B$ ,$b$ and $b'$ are the elements of any ideal of $B$. $x$ is a element of $K$.

$K$ consist of $a/a,a/b,b/a,b/b$

$\color{green} x=a/a' \Rightarrow x\in B~and~x^{-1}\in B$

$\color{green} x=a/b \Rightarrow x^{-1}\in B $

$\color{green} x=b/a \Rightarrow x\in B $

$\color{red} x=b/b' \Rightarrow x\notin B~and~x^{-1}\notin B $

So there no ideal in $B$,if $B$ is a valuation ring

Something seems wrong.

Can someone fix it and tell me what is valuation rings?

Comment: You have lots of "$k=..$ then $x$ such and such". What's the relation between $k$ and $x$?

Comment: I think $x$ is a element of $K$,@AndreaMori

Comment: Just because you cannot immediately deduce from the representation $x=b/b$ that $x \in B$ or $x^{-1} \in B$ does not mean that this does not hold what so ever. In this case $b/b=1$ is most certainly an element of $B$.

Comment: Ok, so $k=x$, then what? Mind that $a/a=b/b=1\in B$ is true for *every* domain.

Comment: I guess you mean to say that "$x = a/a'$ for some unit $a$ and some unit $a'$, or ...". It would help if you actually did so; the problem of (and the solution of) your approach then springs out immediately. In the case $x = b/b'$ for some non-unit $b$ and some non-unit $b'$, you can neither conclude $x \not\in B$ nor $x^{-1} \not \in B$, since $x$ might *also* be of one of the other three forms.

Comment: It looks as if you have just discovered the trivial valuation! But there are other, more interesting valuations as well. Once you figure out what you're asking about here, and continue reading, you will no doubt come across the definition of a valuation very soon. The valuation ring associated to the trivial valuation is the entire field, and this is a nice (if not very interesting) case to examine when reading through definitions to make sure you understand what they say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another good way to understand a valuation ring is "an integral domain whose ideals are linearly ordered."

As such, it has a unique maximal ideal. A trivial example would be a field F, which clearly has that property in its own field of fractions (which is itself.)

If it's not a field, then its unique maximal ideal is nonzero. One example of this is the ring of formal power series $F[[x]]$ inside its field of fractions $F((x))$, the Laurent series.

Given an arbitrary $f\in F((x))$, either $f$ or its inverse has to have lower degree greater than or equal to $0$, and no nonzero coefficients on negative powers of $x$.

Answer (score 4):

I don't follow your reasoning. I think you may be arguing that $K$ has no (nonzero) ideals.

Here is a simple nondegenerate example: let $B$ the the ring of all rational numbers with odd denominator. It is a valuation ring of $\mathbf{Q}$.

$B$ is also a local ring, whose maximal ideal is the one generated by $2$; it is the set of all rational numbers with even numerator and odd denominator.